# How to avoid a line starting with "RE:"?

Tags: python, line

I need to read a file line by line and have to avoid the line starting with 'RE:'. I use this script to achieve the task:

```
from glob import glob
import fileinput
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in fileinput.input(glob('*')):
        if line !='RE:' in line:
            out.write(line)
```

but its work other way around, it just print the lines that's starting with 'RE:'.

What went wrong? and how could this can be modified?

Comment: I think python takes this `if line !='RE:' in line:` as `RE:` in line. ie, it would print only the line which has `RE:`

Answer (score 3):

Change your if statement like this,

```
if not line.startswith('RE:'):
```

If you don't want to touch the line which starts with some particular chars, then use `startswith` function along with `not`.

**Example:**

```
>>> s = '''foo
RE:jhjah
bar'''.splitlines()
>>> for line in s:
        if not line.startswith('RE:'):
            print(line)


foo
bar
>>>
```